# Jscrollpane + Fancybox + Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox, jscrollpane

I'm trying to solve a problem that does not show the JScrollPane on a window ajax Fancybox with row within a structure-fluid bootstrap.

I saw on the net almost all the posts related to the problem, I have tried almost everything, but it really is a problem you can not solve?

I used a file main.js  :  specific code for fancybox whit jscrollpane (no work in firefox)

```
$(".various").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
        maxWidth: 900,
        maxHeight: 400,
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',


        'onComplete': (function(){
           scrollpane = $('.row-fluid #span4project').jScrollPane({showArrows: true, scrollbarWidth : '50'});
        }),
        'onStart' : (function() {

        }),
        'onClose' : (function() {
            scrollpane.destroy();
        })


    });
```

Code for the content in home page (good work in firefox)

```
 if (!$.browser.webkit) {
      $('#content1').jScrollPane();
      $('#content2').jScrollPane();
      $('#content3').jScrollPane();
      $('#content4').jScrollPane();

          }
```

Comment: `onComplete onStart and onClose` are options for fancybox v1.3.x but you seems to be using fancybox v2.x ...check the right [options](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer, i try whit the code support of fancybox 2

this is the code for .various

```
 /* fancybox        ---------------------------------------------         */
    /* profile, research */
    $(".various").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
        maxWidth: 900,
        maxHeight: 400,
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
         afterLoad:function(){

          $('.rowfluid').jScrollPane({width:265, scrollbarWidth:17, scrollbarMargin:10, showArrows:true, arrowSize: 17, wheelSpeed:71});
        }
```